# I get an error creating a react-360 project

Tags: react-native, npm, react-360

I get this error when I start a new react-360 project using react-360 init myProject.It creates the folder but when I npm start it gives me more errors.

```
react-360 init MyProject
(node:17583) ExperimentalWarning: The fs.promises API is experimental
Creating new React 360 project...
Project directory created at MyProject

Copying assets...

Installing dependencies...
(node:17584) ExperimentalWarning: The fs.promises API is experimental
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: MyProject@0.0.1
npm ERR! Found: react@16.3.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"16.3.2" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"16.3.1" from react-native@0.55.4
npm ERR! node_modules/react-native
npm ERR!   react-native@"~0.55.4" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /Users/scylla/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/scylla/.npm/_logs/2021-03-17T10_50_46_670Z-debug.log
`npm` exited with code 1. Try fixing the errors above and run `npm` from within MyProject again.
```

When I run npm start

```
npm start
(node:17675) ExperimentalWarning: The fs.promises API is experimental

> MyProject@0.0.1 start
> node node_modules/react-360/scripts/packager.js

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:638
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '/Users/scylla/Documents/cs/react360test/MyProject/node_modules/react-360/scripts/packager.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
```

Any Ideas on how to solve it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

ok, I just ran npm install --force and it fixed everything!!